# LDRD hard faulting during execution

Tags: assembly, cortex-m

I'm creating a polymorphic-code and I have an issue with the LDRD instruction that is making me crazy, I cannot see it. NMI hardfault at execution obviously.
I'm on a STM32L4A6AG.
Problem probably resides in assembly code but could maybe also be on opcode generation (Ignored by disassembler?).

Data is taken before ldrd execution:

**My code:**

```
2004ffc0: 0xbff36f8f   isb     sy
2004ffc4: 0xbff34f8f   dsb     sy
2004ffc8: 0x000020b5   push    {r5, lr}
2004ffca: 0xdff80c50   ldr.w   r5, [pc, #12]   ; 0x2004ffd8
2004ffce: 0xdfe90301   ldrd    r0, r1, [pc, #12]       ; 0x2004ffdc
2004ffd2: 0x0000a847   blx     r5
2004ffd4: 0x000000bf   nop     
2004ffd6: 0x000020bd   pop     {r5, pc}
```

**Registers:**

```
    r0  0x0 (Hex)   
    r1  0x1 (Hex)   
    r2  0x2004ffc0 (Hex)    
    r3  0x2004ffbf (Hex)    
    r4  0xaabbccdd (Hex)    
    r5  0x80107e1 (Hex) 
    r6  0x0 (Hex)   
    r7  0x2004ff98 (Hex)    
    r8  0   
    r9  0   
    r10 0   
    r11 0   
    r12 0   
    sp  0x2004ff90  
    lr  0x80104ed (Hex) 
    pc  0x2004ffce
```

**Memory:**

```
x/9wx 0x2004ffc0
0x2004ffc0: 0x8f6ff3bf  0x8f4ff3bf  0xf8dfb520  0xe9df500c
0x2004ffd0: 0x47a80103  0xbd20bf00  0x080107e1  0xeeffaabb
0x2004ffe0: 0xaabbccdd

x/18hx 0x2004ffc0
0x2004ffc0: 0xf3bf  0x8f6f  0xf3bf  0x8f4f  0xb520  0xf8df  0x500c  0xe9df
0x2004ffd0: 0x0103  0x47a8  0xbf00  0xbd20  0x07e1  0x0801  0xaabb  0xeeff
0x2004ffe0: 0xccdd  0xaabb
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Interesting.  The code itself doesn't look like it is wrong.  Can you perhaps provide some more context to this?  Perhaps the whole function and what environment you use this on would be useful.

Comment: Updated, if you need something specific please ask me.

Comment: Are you in thumb mode? Did you correctly call this function with LSB set?

Comment: Yep, cortex-m has only thumb mode afaik. The same version of code with LDR instead of LDRD works apparently.

Comment: Kindly do me a favour and try to insert a `nop` before `ldrd`.  The [manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihjffga.html) says something weird about the `ldrd` instruction having to be located on a word aligned address.  Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: I'm missed that note, I think you got it... I'm going to try it and report back

Comment: It was that. Now it working correctly, thanks a lot!

Comment: Interesting! @Damiano, are you writing the assembly yourself or is this from C code? And what compiler version is this? The compiler shouldn't be emitting unaligned ldrd instructions

Comment: Hi, this is writed directly in machine code as I'm practicing some polymorphic code. This is a part of a simple thunk implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ARM manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihjffga.html), `ldrd` instructions with a `pc`-relative addressing mode must be be word-aligned on ARMv7-M parts.  If the assembler does not take care of this quirk, manual alignment may be needed:

```
.align
ldrd r0, r1, [pc, #12]
```